# ¿ Que se debe hacer para tener permisos para poder unir dos módulos de un proyecto sin usar sudo?

Tags: nodejs, ubuntu, permisos

Hola estoy intentando enlazar dos módulos creados por mi, en proyecto creado con Node.js, y como siempre lo hice :
`npm link .` dentro del módulo que quiero llamar, y ya desde el otro llamarle en `package.json`, y me da el siguiente error:

`npm ERR! path /home/miguel/cursos/cursoJs-Node/proyectoMichaelgram/michaelgram-db
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '/home/miguel/cursos/cursoJs-Node/proyectoMichaelgram/michaelgram-db' -> '/usr/lib/node_modules/michaelgram-db'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '/home/miguel/cursos/cursoJs-Node/proyectoMichaelgram/michaelgram-db' -> '/usr/lib/node_modules/michaelgram-db'
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink \'/home/miguel/cursos/cursoJs-Node/proyectoMichaelgram/michaelgram-db\' -> \'/usr/lib/node_modules/michaelgram-db\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!   path: '/home/miguel/cursos/cursoJs-Node/proyectoMichaelgram/michaelgram-db',
npm ERR!   dest: '/usr/lib/node_modules/michaelgram-db' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/miguel/.npm/_logs/2018-07-17T12_02_46_081Z-debug.log`

He visto esos archivos y son propiedad de root . 
Puse una nueva versión de Ubuntu 18.04 he instale node 
¿ Puede ser problema al instalar node ?
No recuerdo como lo hice, pero en ocasiones anteriores no tuve este problema de permisos.
No se si debo desinstalar node y npm he instalarlo de una manera que pueda tener acceso desde cualquier proyecto que hago.
Ya me di problemas otro archivo y corregi utilizando `sudo`, pero no me parece una práctica, pues no deberia de dar problemas, nunca los dio node. 
¿ Que me aconsejan que haga para corregir el problema y tener acceso a node_modules sin utilizar `sudo` ? 
¿ Quizá deba desinstalar e instalar de otra forma ?
Gracias, espero se entienda mi necesidad, perdonen la sintaxis pero debo hacer uso del traductor.
Gracias.

Comment: Creo (no lo puedo confirmar) que el problema es que instalaste node usando apt-get: eso requiere permisos de root. Si en lugar de usar la instalación *normal-global* descargas node desde la página oficial y lo instalas localmente (sólo para tu usuario), tendrás permisos para hacer todo si necesidad de root.

Comment: Gracia@Pablo Lozano, Algo de eso es porque al instalar alguna dependencia en proyecto con `npm`me dijo lo mismo. Osea que lo suyo es desinstalar y volver a instalar...? ¿Como lo haria mejor con :`sudo apt-get purge nodejs` o con: `sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove nodejs`

Comment: Ahí ya no sabría decirte, no soy un experto en debian/ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con la guia de @Pablo Lozano que me orientó hacia el tema de permisos y seguí buscando y preguntando y entre askubuntu.com y stackoverflow.com encontre la solucion.
Desinstale node por completo :
`sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove nodejs`
Elimine todo resto de node y npm:
1. Antes que nada, debe ejecutar el siguiente comando desde el terminal de comando como sudo.
`sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/local/share/man/man1/node* /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d ~/.npm ~/.node-gyp /opt/local/bin/node opt/local/include/node /opt/local/lib/node_modules`

2. Elimine los directorios node o node_modules de / usr / local / lib con la ayuda del siguiente comando:

`sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node*`

3. Elimine los directorios node o node_modules de / usr / local / include con la ayuda del siguiente comando:
   `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/include/node*`
4. Elimine cualquier archivo de nodo o directorio de / usr / local / bin con la ayuda del siguiente comando:

`sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/node*`

Finalmente y como me sugirieron en stackoverflow.com y siguiendo la documentacion de npm(https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions) install node con [nvm](/questions/tagged/nvm)